# LDAP: Filtering using an Attribute that has a forward slash in its name

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

We have an LDAP system with an unknown number of users who have erroneously had a custom attribute added to their account which contains a forward slash in the name

[image]

I want to use our LDAP Browser to figure out how many of these entries there are.

The problem is that I cannot seem to construct a filter based on that attribute name because of the presence of that forward slash in the attribute name causes errors.

Trying something like this

[image]

Results in a "Search Failed" message in my LDAP Browser (It's a Radiant ONE Browser)

If I remove the forward slash and search again I get a "0 entries returned" message as would be expected since I am now searching on an attribute name that does not exist.

I have tried escaping using a backslash but this does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

First, it depends.
As the "Radiant ONE Browser" probably also does some parsing to the values.

Only way I am aware you might is something like:

```
(sn//lastName=*)
```

Generally I would recommend that you fix the attribute within the schema these type of issues only seem to get worse down the road.

Comment: Yeah I had tried that but the browser blew up anytime I placed the forward slash on the left-hand side of that filter expression no matter I preceded or proceeded it with